# What can I get a handle on the target of a fabric js event?

Tags: fabricjs

In [this fabricjs tutorial section](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-2/#events) it says putting listeners right on an object like so

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 50, fill: 'green' });
   rect.on('selected', function() {
   console.log('selected a rectangle');
});
```

That is fine, but I don't want to log a string to the console.  I want to manipulate the rectangle.  Specifically the rectangle isn't selectable by default and based on application state, I need to make it selectable.

I can't figure out how to get a handle on the rectangle from inside the event handler.  How to do that escapes me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example you gave, you have attached the event to the object itself. So you can access the object using `this` or the variable name (which is `rect` in your case). Here is an example

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 50, fill: 'green' });
rect.on('selected', function() {
   console.log(this);
   this.set({width:200});
});
```

Alternatively, if you attach it to the canvas so that it listens to all the `object:selected` events, you can access the object at which the event occurred like this:

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 50, fill: 'green' });
canvas.on('object:selected', function (e) {
    console.log('selected a rectangle');
    e.target.set({width:200});
});
```